# A SSLError when I use Rpush to push notification through GCM in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, google-cloud-messaging

I use `rpush` gem to push notification through `Google Cloud Messaging` in rails application. When I set up the `API_KEY` and `device token`, and push the notification, a `SSLError` occurred

```
[2016-02-11 12:14:46] [ERROR] OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
/Users/huangjun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock'
/Users/huangjun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect'
/Users/huangjun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/Users/huangjun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:858:in `start'
```

What's the problem? Thanks!

My computer is Mac, the os system is `OS X Yosemite 10.10.5`

Comment: What machine are you using?

Comment: @Cyzanfar thanks for your response. It's Mac

Comment: I've had this error in the past. This link was quite helpful: http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: What ruby version are you using?

Comment: @Cyzanfar the ruby version is ruby 2.3.0p0. I have tried the `rvm` solution, but not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this error a couple times while working on different machines. This is often do to your certificate files being outdated.
The most helpful guide has been:  [OpenSSL Errors and Rails – Certificate Verify Failed](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html).

Basically this is what you need to do:

```
$ rvm -v
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

( if you don't have RVM installed go to their [website](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) and follow the instructions)

Comment: I have tried the solution yesterday but it's not work at that moment. However, when I ran my project today, the problem disappeared. I think it must be your solution works. Thanks.